# Disable/Hide checkboxes in a checkbox list given the value of a checkbox (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to disable or hide some checkboxes in a list of checkboxes given a max number of checkboxes allowed to be selected.
i.e. If the value of checkbox is greater that my_value then the checkbox is disabled/hidden and cannot be selected... and work it into this code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Max Number of Checks</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="Check_01" name="FW_check" value="1" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_02" name="FW_check" value="2" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_03" name="FW_check" value="3" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_04" name="FW_check" value="4" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_05" name="FW_check" value="5" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="Check_06" name="FW_check" value="6" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_07" name="FW_check" value="7" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_08" name="FW_check" value="8" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_09" name="FW_check" value="9" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_10" name="FW_check" value="10" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the following:

- `my_value` (the max value of the checkbox) is set somewhere outside of this code
- all checkboxes in the table with name attribute `FW_check` look like the input elements you posted above (mostly meaning that their `value` is a valid number)

That said, I would recommend you do the following:

- Get a list of every `input[name="FW_check"]` within the table, using `document.querySelector`
- Iterate through these checkboxes, check the `value` of the input, and set `disabled = true` if the value is greater than the max value.

Here's some basic code that would accomplish this:

```js
const my_value = // some number that you have defined elsewhere, as mentioned above
const checkboxes = document.querySelector('.table input[name="FW_check"]');
for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
  const value = Number.parseInt(checkbox.value, 10); // note the base 10. in case you accidentally put a 0 before a number, it still parses correctly and doesn't assume base 8
  checkbox.disabled = value > my_value; // this will handle re-enabling the checkbox if this function is run again after my_value drops
}
```

This can of course be run as many times as you want, put in a function, etc.

Comment: Nice.  Instead of `Number.parseInt(checkbox.value, 10)`, `Number(checkbox.value)` is enough.

Comment: That may be true, but I think this way is a much clearer way to show what the intent of the code is. I have never used `Number` myself for that reason, and I just had to test out whether "010" becomes octal or not (it doesn't), which I think is something that would catch other people looking at the code as well.

IMO the only primitive constructor-function that is "OK" to call is `Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question properly , this is what you are looking for .

```js
var max = 5;

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("FW_check");

for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    if(i<max){
    checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
  } else {
    checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Max Number of Checks</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="Check_01" name="FW_check" value="1" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_02" name="FW_check" value="2" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_03" name="FW_check" value="3" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_04" name="FW_check" value="4" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_05" name="FW_check" value="5" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="Check_06" name="FW_check" value="6" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_07" name="FW_check" value="7" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_08" name="FW_check" value="8" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_09" name="FW_check" value="9" type="checkbox" />
          <input id="Check_10" name="FW_check" value="10" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice.  You are assuming the `value`s are in ascending order and/or returned in such order by `document.getElementsByName("FW_check")`.

Comment: document.getElementsByName("FW_check") returns an HTMLCollection object, representing a collection of elements with the specified name. The elements in the returned collection are sorted as they appear in the source code.

Comment: Sure, but there is no guarantee that this person never is going to rearrange these checkboxes. They asked about the value of the checkbox, not the order of it.